# An incomparable rebus

Tags: mathematics, rebus

My first rebus, so I hope that it makes sense.

> Given that $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{(z-A)^n}$, is it true that
>   $A=[N,\ldots,O]$?

Hint:

> $f$, $n$, and $z$ are not important

Hint:

> It's about fruits

Comment: To get started: $A$ is a *pole* of function $f$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The community wiki answer is

> No.

Community wiki argument:

> 1. $A$ is a pole of the function
>  2. $[N..O]$ is the $N$-$O$-range, respectively the EN-O-RANGE.
>  3. Now the question is: IS A-POLE EQUAL TO EN-O-RANGE?
>  4. And the answer is: No, since you cannot compare apples to oranges.

Comment: oh wow, this is a way better answer than I was expecting out of this puzzle

Comment: Well done! And by the way, what is the community wiki (I'm new here)?

Comment: @fffred A community wiki is an answer editable by anyone with a reputation above 100 (Rather than 2000). Wikis do not affect reputation in any way. Here is a link to more info:https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Answer (score 5):

Another try - is it?

> There is no answer - i.e. it cannot be deduced

because

> The rebus last line is comparing apples and oranges

as

> Apples is A pole (plural as pole of degree n)

and

> oranges is 0 (zero) ranges as No is the range or interval.

Comment: You're almost there. But I'm not sure I understand the reasoning for the latter. Think pronunciation. In any case, what is the answer to "is the following true?"

Comment: +1, but I think the latter part is supposed to come from pronouncing "N-O range"

Comment: I agree with the above comments - that would make a good answer (I couldn't quite get it and I edited my answer a few times already - not sure of the protocol of editing an already posted answer - and thanks also for correcting the format earlier.)

Answer (score 2):

Is it:-

> Poles apart ?

Because

> $A$ is a pole of the function in variable $z$ and these letters are distant from each other in the alphabet(similar to the poles of a magnet).
>  It may be noted that a monopole does not exist, 
> so the South and North Pole of a magnet are always some distance apart,
> howsoever small this distance might be.

---

So the following (ie.$A=[N\,.\!.\, O]$) is:

> False, as $O$ and $N$ are not poles apart(ie. far apart) in the alphabet.

Comment: Nice idea, but that's not the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Is it:

> An apple a day keeps the doctor away.

Because

> Apple is A pole
>  Doctor away is Dr No separated

Comment: It's not about Dr No :)

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> A Polar Molecule?

So the following (ie.$A=[N..O]$) is :

> True, as $[N..O]$ (read as $N$ to $O$),ie. $N_2O$ is a polar molecule.

Comment: Another interesting interpretation! The one I'm thinking about still has a better match.